# Tooltip width with relative positiong

Tags: tooltip, css

How can I change my tool-tip so that it has a working auto width. I think the problem is at the relative position of the link.

See here my problem http://jsfiddle.net/kzJRW/

How can I fix this and the tooltip works still as I defined.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kzJRW/13/

The `white-space` property helps not break words.  I also rearranged some of your declarations, non-changing values such as layout positioning and box-shadow colors don't need to be declared in the :hover pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

@shub; you need to just write `white-space:nowrap;`

like this:

```
.tooltip span {
    margin-left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/kzJRW/14/

Answer (score -1):

in a tag along with `position:relative` give `display:block`

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kzJRW/9/

Comment: is not a best solution because if you define width to your a tag then your tooltip is also wrap . Right now it's take width 100% :)

Comment: @sandeep But here shub asked he has auto width tooltip. Its exact solution for his requirement, setting width is not occurring in OPs question, If general Solution you may be right ..

Comment: @gtmail; yes the he want auto width of tooltip but not anchor tag